# Why will my Handlebars page not render using Express with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, handlebars.js

When I attempt to run my Node.js project, the page that is rendered is blank, regardless of what I put in the "Login.handlebars" file. If I put HTML in the "main.handlebars" file, the result will be displayed, and I am not sure as to why that occurs either.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
const handlebars = require('express-handlebars');
const path = require('path');
const handlebars_inst = handlebars.create({
    extname: '.handlebars',
    compilerOptions: {
        preventIndent: true
    },
    pagesDir: path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'pages'),
    layoutsDir: path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'layouts'),
    partialsDir: path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'partials')
});

app.engine('handlebars', handlebars_inst.engine)
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars')
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'pages'))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {

  res.redirect('/user/login')
})

app.get('/user/login', (req, res) => {
    res.render("Login", {test: "Hello"})

})


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

My expectation for the above code is that it would redirect from the homepage, which is blank, to the Login page, which contains only the single line:

```
<p>Hello World</P>
```

However, it instead renders a blank page. I believe I have all the correct dependencies installed, but the JSON file is included below. The following is the structure of the project folder:

```
- node_modules
- views
   -layouts
      -main.handlebars
   -pages
      -Account.handlebars
      -Login.handlebars
      -SignUp.handlebars
   -partials
-app.js
-package-lock.json
-package.json
```

```
{
  "name": "pa4",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon app.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-handlebars": "^6.0.6",
    "express-session": "^1.17.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20"
  }
}
```

You can assume that all files aside from the JSON lock package are empty if I did not include their contents in the post.

Thank you all for any help you can offer.

Comment: What does your `main.handlebars` layout look like?

Comment: There is nothing in it currently. If I put HTMl there then that HTML renders.

Comment: You would need to add `{{{body}}}` to the layout file in order for it to render a view inside of it. See the docs at: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars

Comment: Okay, thank you! That worked. I had read through the documentation several times, but I did not realize the purpose/necessity of the main file.